# Conditional popup using AMPscript

Tags: ampscript, marketing-cloud

I am using the AMPscript redirect-function to redirect to a thankyou page once a successful insert is completed.

```
IF NOT EMPTY (@Status) THEN

    Redirect(Concat("https://pages.email.test.com/test-conf/?email=",@Email))

ENDIF
```

But instead of the redirect i want to display a pop-up modal to the user. How can we achieve that?

Comment: AMPScript is server-side (evaluated _before_ the page is loaded) and pop-up modals are client-side (evaluated _as or after_ the page is loaded).

Answer (score 1):

Just add the If-statement as a single-line AMPScript and place the html/js code that generates the modal/alert between this line and the single-line AMPScript containing the end of the if-statement. Some examples that suit your use case can be found in the marketing cloud documentation: [AMPscript 301](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/getting_started_with_ampscript/ampscript_301/)

```
%%[ IF NOT EMPTY (@Status) THEN ]%%
    <!-- place your alert/modal-code here -->
%%[ ENDIF ]%%
```